# Какая из операций изменяет строку s? Python

Tags: python

```
s[0]='A'
s[:]=*
s.replace('a','A')
```

Comment: Ни одна не изменит. Нельзя просто взять и изменить строку в Python.

Comment: Скопипастили задание откуда-то?

Comment: @andreymal самое смешное, если из собеседования.

Answer (score 1):

Строка неизменяемый объект,
но если бы она была изменяемой, то вела бы себя так:

```
class Str(list):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr
        return self

    def __repr__(self): return ''.join(self)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = getattr(repr(self), self.attr)(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(res, str):
            self[:] = res
        return res

A = Str('mystring')
print(id(A), A)

A[:] = 'newstring'
A.upper()
print(id(A), A)

A.replace('NEW', 'replace')
print(id(A), A)

print(A.endswith('STRING'))
```

out:

```
59139008 mystring
59139008 NEWSTRING
59139008 replaceSTRING
True
```

Comment: Вообще-то этот функционал реализуется одним классом: http://ideone.com/6ZhzOo

Comment: тогда пришлось бы описывать все методы str

Comment: Я считаю, лучше все прописать явно, чтобы потом не было неожиданностей. К тому же, пример игрушечный - вряд ли кому-то на практике понадобится полная реализация изменяемой строки на Python.